# WSO2 APIM - api file deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

deploying the WSO2 APIM 2.1.0 using puppet, we consider to deploy the API itself with the CICD as well.

In theory - I could copy (template) the synapse files (proxy, api) and the api is available for the call, however - the API is not visible in the store. I assume there's more data in the database than just a synapse config file.

Is there a way to define / deploy API (including to the store) using the configuration files or it needs to be done manually?

Edit:
I thought there's a way to deploy API using the API Admin Services. But when calling addAPI with the metadata XML, looks ok. But trying to see the API in the publisher throws an exception

`ERROR - index:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Unable to find the API: admin-myapi-v1.0.0 in the database`

Thank you for any hint

g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements it looks like you can use one of the following options.

1. [Migrate APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment) - You can export APIs from one environment and import those APIs to the new environment. When you import APIs in the new environment, those APIs will be in created state. You need to manually publish those APIs. May be using the jaggery API or REST API you will be able to publish the APIs.
2. [REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/publisher/)
3. [Jaggery API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Publisher+APIs) - This is deprecated at the moment and discourage for using this.

Once you create the APIs, APIs related details will be saved in the database. Additionally, synapse configuration can be found in the file system. If you point the previous database to the new deployment and deploy the synapse artifacts, APIs will work. But then again API creation/publishing and entire flow will not be tested. For CICD, you need to consider above mentioned options. In the future releases, there is more focus towards the REST API and it will be more useful for the CICD.

Comment: That I was looking for, thank you for the answer and references