# WSO2 REST request to create new API?

Tags: rest, wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to found out how to send a REST request to WSO2's publisher to create a new API without out having to utilize the UI at all. Can anyone help point me in the right directions as to how to start to do this?

Thank you

Comment: please have a look at the REST API link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140496/wso2-apim-api-file-deployment

Comment: next to that the REST api in the documentation may have different url (version part) depending in the version you use. check in your webapp folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Publisher REST API docs here.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/index.html#guide